# USB debugging on Samsung tablet with a mac

Tags: android, macos, samsung-mobile

I have got a MacBook Pro (Late 2011) and a Samsung galaxy tab 8.9 with Android 4.0.4. Now I want to debug some Apps developed with Eclipse on the tablet. The problem I have is that I have access on files, which are stored on the tablet but Samsung Kies and Eclipse can't find the device.
I also attempt to connect the device to a windows-pc, what works correctly.
Is there any opportunity to debug on the tablet?? (I don't want to root it!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add your tablet's **usb vendor id** to adb_usb.ini file in /Users/[your name]/.android folder, your tablet's vendor id maybe is 0x04e8(if you can't find it in this list [USB Vendor IDs](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#VendorIds), you can find it in your **System Information.app**); then follow the step 3 in http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up (the ubuntu step on your mac);  finaly restart adb server.

**The Result:**

```
$ cat /Users/[your name]/.android/adb_usb.ini 
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
0x04e8

$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
$ adb devices
```

I don't have Samsung galaxy tab but it works for my tablet.